# Clean urls - When I use a dash for a space, what should I use for dash?

Tags: php

I have a page that creates a link (clean url) to an article

```
weburl.com/Title-article
```

A RewriteRule in .htaccess then rewrites the url to

```
weburl.com/articles.php?title=Title-article
```

On articles.php I'm displaying the title after SQL security checks and changing the dash into a whitespace.

```
$title_dashed = trim_strip_data($_GET['title']); //trim_strip_data() is a custom function that strips unnecessary characters like backslashes and extra white space.
$title = preg_replace("/[-]/", " ", $title_dashed);
echo "$title";
```

This all works fine but what should I do / use when I have a dash in the title (fe. "T-shirts") and I want that dash to be displayed and not to be removed from the title?

Titles can be user generated and I don't want to restrict dashes in the title.

Comment: can you clarify your question in last line ? could not understand it.

Comment: Well, if I replace the dash (preg_replace()) to a white space, the dash in the title will be gone. But that I do not want when there is a dash in the title like in "T-shirt".

Comment: Personally I'd omit the dash but if you leave it in things will still be readable

Comment: This is a design choice, there is no right or wrong answer

Comment: mostly it is not direct title that is passed in url, it is `slug` that is passed or used with urls.

Comment: @Alex The thing is that the titles can be user generated and I don't want to restrict dashes in the title.